# I use react-native track-player, I can't play multiple tracks

Tags: react-native

I am trying to play multiple audio tracks. To do this, I created masses of tracks. Created several TouchableOpacity and showed an object from an array for each. But the player only plays the first track, no matter which one I click.

https://github.com/DoubleSymmetry/react-native-track-player

> I use react-native track-player

```
import React, {Component, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';
import {ScrollView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import ProgressSlider from '../assets/player/ProgressSlider';
import TrackPlayer, {
  State as TrackPlayerState,
  STATE_PAUSED,
  STATE_PLAYING,
  STATE_STOPPED,
  Track,
} from 'react-native-track-player';

import colors from '../assets/colors/colors';
import Fon from "../assets/images/Fon2.png";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

import { InterstitialAd, RewardedAd, BannerAd, TestIds } from '@react-native-firebase/admob';
const adUnitId = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111';
 import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';


var isPaused;
isPaused === STATE_PAUSED;

var isPlaying;
isPlaying === STATE_PLAYING;


const Hizbu2 = () => {
  const ad =    <BannerAd unitId={adUnitId}   size={'SMART_BANNER'}/>
  const [subscription,setSubscription] = useState()
  useEffect(()=>{
     const storage = async()=>{
        let subs = await AsyncStorage.getItem("subscription");

    setSubscription(subs)

  }



  storage()
  },[])
React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(() => {
        console.log('Player is setup');
      });
      TrackPlayer.registerPlaybackService(() =>
        require('../services/trackPlayerServices'),
      );
      await TrackPlayer.add(track);
    })();    
  }, []);


  const track = [ {
    id: 1,
    url: require('../assets/audio/hizbu.mp3'),
    title: 'Track Title',
    artist: 'Track Artist',
    artwork: '',
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    url: require('../assets/audio/hizbu2.mp3'),
    title: 'Track Title',
    artist: 'Track Artist',
    artwork: '',
  },


]
  




    
  return(
 
    <View style ={styles.container} >
    <ImageBackground source={Fon} style={styles.ImBackground}>
        <ScrollView>
        <Text style = {styles.titlePlayer} >Намерение</Text>
        <View style={styles.player}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => TrackPlayer.play()}>
            <Icon name="play-circle" size={40} color='#000000'/>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => TrackPlayer.pause()}>
            <Icon name="pause-circle" size={40} color='#000000'/>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <View style={styles.slider}>
            <ProgressSlider />
          </View>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => TrackPlayer.stop()}>
            <Icon name="stop-circle" size={40} color='#000000'/>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => 
          {track[0]
            TrackPlayer.play()
          }}>
           <Text style={styles.textArabBold}>track1</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>


          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => 
          {track[1]
            TrackPlayer.play()
          }}>
           <Text style={styles.textArabBold}>track2</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could so somthing like this. But this could lead to performance issues.

```js
import TrackPlayer as TrackPlayer1 from 'react-native-track-player'
import TrackPlayer as TrackPlayer2 from 'react-native-track-player'
```

Check issue [here.](https://github.com/DoubleSymmetry/react-native-track-player/issues/172)

Comment: import { default as TrackPlayerTwo } from "react-native-track-player";